# multilevel model specification

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

We had participants complete a virtual maze. We showed the participants the correct path through the maze, then had them complete the maze 10 times. The maze consisted of 15 decision points, which are places where the participant must turn right or left. If the participant went the incorrect direction, they were corrected and put back on the correct path. We have data recorded at each decision point (correct or incorrect). Further, 5 of the decision points contained a special landmark, 5 contained a 'plain' landmark, and 5 contained no landmark.

Our data looks like this (note: trial is coded from 0-9 with trial = 0 being the first trial):
[image]

Our research questions were:

1. How do participants learn across trials?
2. Is the learning curve different depending on the type of landmark at the decision point.

I have tried to model the data in two ways. I am not sure which specification is correct. I am using the `lme4` package in R, though I am not set on that for any specific reason. As a side note, I'm also trying to mimic the modeling process using the `brms` package.

First, I tried:

```
m1 <- glmer(correct ~ 1 + trial + saliency + (1| decisionPoint) + (1 | participant),
                             data = df,
                             family="binomial")
```

Next, I tried:

```
m2 <- glmer(correct ~ 1 + trial + saliency + (1 | decisionPoint) + (1 | trial) + (1 | trial:participant),
                             data = df,
                             family="binomial")
```

The results of model m1 appear to fit my expectations. However, my concerns persist. I just don't feel confident that I am doing everything correctly.

I have posted some sample data here (note the variable names are slightly different): [GoFile](https://gofile.io/d/qSzHo9)

I'm very grateful for your thoughts!

Comment: Are you more interested in learning about the individual participants or the participants as a whole (i.e. average learning) or both?

Comment: I am mainly interested in the average learning effect (though, substantial individual differences are also interesting). I would also like to do some exploratory analyses to see what correlates with individual learning trajectories.